# Access list elements to insert in Database

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, console-application

I have to insert this SVG file into database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 655 714" style="enable-background:new 0 0 655 714;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.4252;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{font-family:'ArialMT';}
    .st2{font-size:4.4px;}
    .st3{font-size:4.0619px;}
    .st4{font-size:4.4848px;}
    .st5{font-family:'CenturyGothic';}
    .st6{font-size:5.3818px;}
    .st7{font-size:4.862px;}
    .st8{font-size:2.9424px;}
    .st9{font-size:5.3817px;}
    .st10{font-size:5.5371px;}
    .st11{font-family:'FuturaBT-Medium';}
    .st12{font-size:7.0621px;}
    .st13{font-size:5.6497px;}
</style>
<g id="INSERT_228_">
    <g id="POLYLINE">
        <polyline class="st0" points="582.3,29.3 489.3,29.3 489.3,161.1 472.8,161.1 472.8,381.8 9.2,381.8 9.2,550.9 91.1,550.9 
            91.1,688.8 404.2,688.8 404.2,672.1 613.8,672.1 613.8,551 568,551 568,161.9 582.3,161.9 582.3,29.3       "/>
    </g>
    <g id="SS06">
        <rect x="200.3" y="504.5" class="st0" width="76.2" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 202.121 540.6375)" class="st1 st2">SS06</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS22">
        <rect x="292.4" y="469.6" class="st0" width="38.1" height="19"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 294.1578 487.368)" class="st1 st2">SS22</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS24">
        <rect x="292.4" y="504.5" class="st0" width="76.2" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 294.123 540.6375)" class="st1 st2">SS24</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS18">
        <rect x="13" y="479.1" class="st0" width="76.2" height="63.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 15.1014 540.2482)" class="st1 st2">SS18</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS23">
        <rect x="330.5" y="469.6" class="st0" width="38.1" height="19"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 357.6646 487.1672)" class="st1 st2">SS23</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS21">
        <rect x="330.5" y="450.5" class="st0" width="38.1" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 357.6647 454.7141)" class="st1 st2">SS21</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS28">
        <rect x="425.8" y="504.5" class="st0" width="38.1" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 451.0888 540.6377)" class="st1 st2">SS28</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS27">
        <rect x="387.7" y="504.5" class="st0" width="38.1" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 389.792 540.9427)" class="st1 st2">SS27</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS26">
        <rect x="387.7" y="450.5" class="st0" width="78.2" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 389.7925 487.3685)" class="st1 st2">SS26</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS25">
        <rect x="387.5" y="396.3" class="st0" width="76.6" height="38.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 389.7921 433.5091)" class="st1 st2">SS25</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS32">
        <rect x="479.7" y="504.5" class="st0" width="76.3" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 481.5829 540.3324)" class="st1 st2">SS32</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS30">
        <rect x="479.5" y="396.3" class="st0" width="76.6" height="38.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 481.5831 433.5082)" class="st1 st2">SS30</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS36">
        <rect x="479.7" y="352.1" class="st0" width="25.4" height="19"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 481.5835 370.0043)" class="st1 st2">SS36</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS33">
        <rect x="479.7" y="333" class="st0" width="25.4" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 481.5836 337.4037)" class="st1 st2">SS33</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS42">
        <rect x="517.8" y="298.1" class="st0" width="38" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 543.9044 315.6991)" class="st1 st2">SS42</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS39">
        <rect x="479.7" y="279" class="st0" width="38.1" height="38.2"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 481.584 315.6996)" class="st1 st2">SS39</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS41">
        <rect x="536.8" y="279" class="st0" width="19.1" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 544.0334 283.5067)" class="st1 st2">SS41</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS49">
        <rect x="479.7" y="244.3" class="st0" width="19" height="18.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9286 -1.050466e-04 1.204293e-04 1 481.8765 260.9377)" class="st1 st3">SS49</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS46">
        <rect x="536.8" y="225.1" class="st0" width="19.1" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 543.6462 229.5146)" class="st1 st2">SS46</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS43">
        <rect x="479.5" y="224.9" class="st0" width="19.5" height="19.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 481.5837 229.515)" class="st1 st2">SS43</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS53">
        <g>
            <rect x="517.8" y="190.1" class="st0" width="38" height="19.1"/>
        </g>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 543.9044 207.2685)" class="st1 st2">SS53</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS51">
        <g>
            <rect x="479.7" y="171.1" class="st0" width="38.1" height="19.1"/>
        </g>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 481.5843 175.4545)" class="st1 st2">SS51</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS38">
        <rect x="530.5" y="352.1" class="st0" width="25.3" height="19"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 544.0338 370.1347)" class="st1 st2">SS38</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS31">
        <rect x="479.7" y="450.5" class="st0" width="76.3" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 481.5835 487.1674)" class="st1 st2">SS31</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS52">
        <g>
            <rect x="479.7" y="190.1" class="st0" width="38.1" height="19.1"/>
        </g>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 482.0323 207.2679)" class="st1 st2">SS52</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS35">
        <rect x="530.5" y="333" class="st0" width="25.3" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 543.6471 337.4033)" class="st1 st2">SS35</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS16">
        <rect x="108" y="450.3" class="st0" width="38.4" height="13.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 111.4612 459.9469)" class="st1 st2">SS16</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS09">
        <rect x="200.3" y="469.6" class="st0" width="50.8" height="19"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 202.1215 486.5066)" class="st1 st2">SS09</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS07">
        <rect x="200.3" y="450.5" class="st0" width="50.8" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 202.121 456.7469)" class="st1 st2">SS07</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS19">
        <rect x="251.1" y="469.6" class="st0" width="25.4" height="19"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 264.4966 486.5062)" class="st1 st2">SS19</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS20">
        <rect x="292.4" y="450.5" class="st0" width="38.1" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 294.1217 454.7146)" class="st1 st2">SS20</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS48">
        <rect x="498.8" y="244.1" class="st0" width="19.1" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 504.8678 261.7213)" class="st1 st2">SS48</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS44">
        <rect x="498.6" y="224.9" class="st0" width="19.5" height="19.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 505.4529 229.604)" class="st1 st2">SS44</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS47">
        <rect x="517.8" y="244.1" class="st0" width="38" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 543.0709 261.7207)" class="st1 st2">SS47</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS45">
        <rect x="517.5" y="224.8" class="st0" width="19.5" height="19.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 524.3689 229.6047)" class="st1 st2">SS45</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS40">
        <rect x="517.8" y="279" class="st0" width="19" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 519.0959 283.5067)" class="st1 st2">SS40</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS37">
        <rect x="505.1" y="352.1" class="st0" width="25.4" height="19"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 507.9546 370.0031)" class="st1 st2">SS37</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS34">
        <rect x="505.1" y="333" class="st0" width="25.4" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 507.9557 337.4035)" class="st1 st2">SS34</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS50">
        <g>
            <rect x="517.8" y="171.1" class="st0" width="38" height="19.1"/>
        </g>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 543.2034 175.4541)" class="st1 st2">SS50</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS15">
        <rect x="146.1" y="450.3" class="st0" width="38.5" height="13.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.531916e-04 1.702129e-04 1 170.4282 459.9478)" class="st1 st2">SS15</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS17">
        <rect x="324.2" y="396.5" class="st0" width="19" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 330.1946 401.6645)" class="st1 st4">SS17</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS08">
        <rect x="251.1" y="450.5" class="st0" width="25.4" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 264.4968 455.5882)" class="st1 st2">SS08</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS02">
        <rect x="108" y="478.9" class="st0" width="76.6" height="63.9"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 0 0 1 109.3252 540.248)" class="st1 st2">SS02</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS13">
        <rect x="324.2" y="415.6" class="st0" width="44.5" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 354.4122 433.4468)" class="st1 st4">SS13</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1.0543 5.501365e-03 -5.217977e-03 1 326.5814 424.6328)" class="st5 st6">Testing Banner</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS14">
        <rect x="343.2" y="396.4" class="st0" width="25.4" height="19.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 356.1604 401.3343)" class="st1 st4">SS14</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1 5.218023e-03 -5.217971e-03 1 344.3441 406.3805)" class="st5 st6">Aqua</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS11">
        <rect x="238.2" y="396.3" class="st0" width="38.5" height="38.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 260.3292 433.241)" class="st1 st4">SS11</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1.1069 5.218016e-03 -4.714038e-03 1 239.4776 416.2588)" class="st5 st7">Rich Interiors</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS05">
        <rect x="200.1" y="396.3" class="st0" width="38.5" height="38.5"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 201.3555 433.036)" class="st1 st4">SS05</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1 5.218023e-03 -5.217971e-03 1 209.7535 416.1146)" class="st5 st6">O&apos;&apos;Prime</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS12">
        <rect x="292.4" y="396.5" class="st0" width="31.8" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 292.9132 433.5077)" class="st1 st4">SS12</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1.0301 5.217937e-03 -4.835421e-03 1 294.207 414.3833)" class="st5 st8">Al Rugaib Interiors</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS01">
        <rect x="13" y="421.9" class="st0" width="31.7" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 14.0635 457.5413)" class="st1 st4">SS01</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 18.9529 443.0661)" class="st5 st9">Nano</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS10">
        <rect x="108.2" y="396.5" class="st0" width="76.2" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 109.3213 432.1395)" class="st1 st4">SS10</text>
        <text id="Qatar_Development_Bank" transform="matrix(0.7912 0 0 1 111.3252 414.3945)" class="st5 st10">Qatar Development Bank (QDB)</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS03">
        <rect x="13" y="396.5" class="st0" width="76.2" height="25.4"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 15.0975 401.8253)" class="st1 st4">SS03</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 31.7155 411.5282)" class="st11 st12">Migalo Home</text>
    </g>
    <g id="SS04">
        <rect x="44.7" y="421.9" class="st0" width="44.5" height="38.1"/>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9 -1.050466e-04 1.167184e-04 1 76.5518 457.6346)" class="st1 st4">SS04</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 52.9853 441.2652)" class="st11 st13">Mardesign</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I have created a class for it

namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "style", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public class Style
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "polyline", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class Polyline
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "class")]
    public string Class { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "points")]
    public string Points { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "g", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class G
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "polyline", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public Polyline Polyline { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "rect", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public Rect Rect { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "text", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public List<Text> Text { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "g", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public List<G> G1 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rect", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class Rect
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "x")]
    public string X { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "y")]
    public string Y { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "class")]
    public string Class { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "width")]
    public string Width { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "height")]
    public string Height { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "text", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class Text
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "transform")]
    public string Transform { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "class")]
    public string Class { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "svg", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class Svg
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "style", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public Style Style { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "style")]
    public string _Style { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "g", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public G G { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xlink", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xlink { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "x")]
    public string X { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "y")]
    public string Y { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "viewBox")]
    public string ViewBox { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "space", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string Space { get; set; }
}
```

}

The code for insert that I have tried is as follows:

class program
{
static string _svgUri = @"D:\InsertHallIntoDB\InsertHallIntoDB\Files\NewGroupedmap29oct(1)(1).svg";
        static string _connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=FloorPlan;Integrated Security=True";
        static SqlConnection _connection = null;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Svg));
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(_svgUri))
            {
                Svg fileSvg = (Svg)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
              //  TruncateTable();
                //Console.WriteLine(fileSvg);
                List<G> recordsToInsert = new List<G>();

                using (_connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    _connection.Open();

                    foreach (G fileItem in fileSvg.G.G1)
                    {
                        if (fileItem.Rect != null)
                        {
                            InsertRect(fileItem);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseDBConnection();
        }
    }

    static void InsertRect(G fileGroup)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO New_Map(Stand_number,Banner_Name,Shape_Type,Height,Width) Values(@Stand_number, @Banner_Name,@Shape_Type,@Height,@Width)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stand_number", fileGroup.Id ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            //need to insert a banner name here, you can check svg file for it. for example Mardesign
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Banner_Name", fileGroup.Text.Where(c => !c.Text1.Any(char.IsDigit)) ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            if (fileGroup.Rect != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shape_Type", "Rectangle");
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", fileGroup.Rect.Height ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Width", fileGroup.Rect.Width ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    static void CloseDBConnection()
    {
        if (_connection != null && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

}

The issue is, I have to insert text as banner name but i am unable to access text element.Please response.

Comment: The error is "No mapping exists from object type System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1"

Comment: issue is resolved now
below is the correct code:

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Xml2CSharp;

namespace InsertHallIntoDB
{
    class Program
    {

        static string _svgUri = @"D:\InsertHallIntoDB\InsertHallIntoDB\Files\NewGroupedmap29oct(1)(1).svg";
        static string _connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=FloorPlan;Integrated Security=True";
        static SqlConnection _connection = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Svg));
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(_svgUri))
                {
                    Svg fileSvg = (Svg)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                  //  TruncateTable();
                    //Console.WriteLine(fileSvg);
                    List<G> recordsToInsert = new List<G>();

                    using (_connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                    {
                        _connection.Open();

                        foreach (G fileItem in fileSvg.G.G1)
                        {
                            if (fileItem.Rect != null)
                            {
                                InsertRect(fileItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseDBConnection();
            }
        }

        static void InsertRect(G fileGroup)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO New_Map(Stand_number,Banner_Name,Shape_Type,Height,Width) Values(@Stand_number, @Banner_Name,@Shape_Type,@Height,@Width)";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stand_number", fileGroup.Id ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                //need to insert a banner name here, you can check svg file for it. for example Mardesign
                var value = fileGroup.Text.Find(c => !c.Text1.Any(char.IsDigit));
                if (value != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Banner_Name", value.Text1 ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Banner_Name", "Null");
                }
                if (fileGroup.Rect != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shape_Type", "Rectangle");
                }
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", fileGroup.Rect.Height ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Width", fileGroup.Rect.Width ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        static void CloseDBConnection()
        {
            if (_connection != null && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _connection.Close();
            }
        }
        static void TruncateTable()
        {
            try
            {
                using (_connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    // Open your connection
                    _connection.Open();
                    //Change the table name here
                    string sql = "truncate table New_Map";
                    // Create the Command and Parameter objects.                 
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseDBConnection();
            }
        }
    }
}

    enter code here
```